# Need package to import in mule

Tags: mule, maven-2

i need to import those package while i build from git maven (mule)

so my script is having those to get imported?

```
import org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.SOAPClient;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;
import org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate;
import org.springframework.ws.client.support.interceptor.ClientInterceptor;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor;
```

So i think i need example pom.xml file with repo urls, i have tried to search but i stuck on

org.opensaml.ws.soap.client
and
org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j

Any advice?

Update : i have added your repos in pom.xml file however i'm receiving those errros while i build

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1-jboss-2:compile (default-compile) on project vancho-mvp: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
79158 [ERROR] /builds/home/app1/src/main/java/com/van2/soap/client/SubscriberClient.java:[4,42] package org.springframework.ws.client.core does not exist
79158 [ERROR] /builds/home/app1/src/main/java/com/van2/soap/client/SubscriberClient.java:[14,17] cannot find symbol
79159 [ERROR] symbol:   class WebServiceTemplate
79159 [ERROR] location: class com.van2.soap.client.SubscriberClient
79159 [ERROR] /builds/home/app1/src/main/java/com/van2/soap/config/SoapConfig.java:[3,35] package org.opensaml.ws.soap.client does not exist
79160 [ERROR] /builds/home/app1/src/main/java/com/van2/soap/config/SoapConfig.java:[8,36] package org.springframework.oxm.jaxb does not exist
79160 [ERROR] /builds/home/app1/src/main/java/com/van2/soap/config/SoapConfig.java:[9,42] package org.springframework.ws.client.core does not exist
79160 [ERROR] /builds/home/app1/src/main/java/com/van2/soap/config/SoapConfig.java:[10,57] package org.springframework.ws.client.support.interceptor does not exist
79161 [ERROR] /builds/home/app1/src/main/java/com/van2/soap/config/SoapConfig.java:[11,50] package org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j does not exist
79161 [ERROR] /builds/home/app1/src/main/java/com/van2/soap/config/SoapConfig.java:[29,16] cannot find symbol
79161 [ERROR] symbol:   class Jaxb2Marshaller
79162 [ERROR] location: class com.van2.soap.config.SoapConfig
79162 [ERROR] /builds/home/app1/src/main/java/com/van2/soap/config/SoapConfig.java:[35,16] cannot find symbol
79162 [ERROR] symbol:   class Wss4jSecurityInterceptor
79162 [ERROR] location: class com.van2.soap.config.SoapConfig
79163 [ERROR] /builds/home/app1/src/main/java/com/van2/soap/config/SoapConfig.java:[45,12] cannot find symbol
79163 [ERROR] symbol:   class WebServiceTemplate
79163 [ERROR] location: class com.van2.soap.config.SoapConfig
79164 [ERROR] /builds/home/app1/src/main/java/com/van2/soap/client/PrepaidPackageClient.java:[4,42] package org.springframework.ws.client.core does not exist
79164 [ERROR] /builds/home/app1/src/main/java/com/van2/soap/client/PrepaidPackageClient.java:[14,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebServiceTemplate
```

Update again after editing pom.xml (update 2 aled) :

```
82900 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1-jboss-2:compile (default-compile) on project vancho-mvp: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
82900 [ERROR] /builds/home/app1/src/main/java/com/van2/soap/config/SoapConfig.java:[3,35] package org.opensaml.ws.soap.client does not exist
82900 [ERROR] /builds/home/app1/src/main/java/com/van2/soap/config/SoapConfig.java:[11,50] package org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j does not exist
82901 [ERROR] /builds/home/app1/src/main/java/com/van2/soap/config/SoapConfig.java:[35,16] cannot find symbol
82901 [ERROR] symbol:   class Wss4jSecurityInterceptor
```

Update 3 for aled :

```
81466 [ERROR] /builds/home/app1/src/main/java/com/van2/soap/config/SoapConfig.java:[11,50] package org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j does not exist
81467 [ERROR] /builds/home/app1/src/main/java/com/van2/config/SoapConfig.java:[35,16] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Wss4jSecurityInterceptor
  location: class com.van2.soap.config.SoapConfig
```

Comment: Are these packages needed to build a Java source in your Mule application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the version of OpenSAML your project uses is very old, in [end of life and abandoned](https://shibboleth.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OpenSAML/pages/1573290009/OS1Status). Note that there are active security vulnerabilities mentioned in the mvnrepository link in the comment. It is very risky to use this old software:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.opensaml/openws -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>openws</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Spring WS last release:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.ws/spring-ws-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.ws/spring-ws-security -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hello @aled i have added those repos to my pom.xml and i get those maven errors while i wanted to build...Still the  opensaml cannot be reconized..

Comment: Exactly the same original error that you posted, or are there any changes in the messages?

Comment: Hi @aled, i have updated my original post 
the errors are bellow this line : 

Update : i have added your repos in pom.xml file however i'm receiving those errros while i build

Please check original post

Comment: It seems that the opensaml error disappears. The Spring WS missing package should be easy to solve with a few google searches. I'll take a look when I'm back at the computer.

Comment: On review I noticed I copied a dependency for a different Spring product. I have now updated the answer with the right dependencies for Spring WS. Let me know if there are missing classes yet.

Comment: Hello thanks so much @aled, i have updated the original post.

The errors are appearing after this line : Update again after editing pom.xml (update 2 aled) :

Comment: It seems that your project uses a very old version of OpenSAML. I'm updating the dependency.  About the error  for `org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j`, did you add the dependency for spring-ws-security?

Comment: Yes i have added those and i have updated again new line on original document

Comment: I see that your project uses older versions of the Spring WS dependencies too. I updated the answer with a previous version that contains the missing package.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it's working finally!